# Deriving single linear regression parameters in terms of multiple linear regression parameters

Tags: regression, econometrics

Suppose the true population model is

$$\ln(wage) = B_0 + B_1 \cdot education + B_2 \cdot experience + v,$$

where $v$ is the error term.

Suppose the model is estimated as

$$\ln(wage) = B_3 + B_4 \cdot education + u$$

How do I calculate each of $B_4$, $E[B_4]$, and $\mathrm{plim}[B_4]$ as a function of $B_1$, $B_2$, and other variables?

Comment: Is this for a class? If so, please add the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\rm Cov} \newcommand{\expr}{\rm expr} \newcommand{\educ}{\rm educ} \newcommand{\Var}{\rm Var}$This is a case of omitted variable bias (OVB). Here the "short model" has suffers from it since the true model contains also the variable experience. (I also guess that you are given the assumption of $E[v | \educ]==E[v | \expr]=0$ in some form?). The key here is to substitute the "true model" into the "false model".

Ignoring the intercepts (you can demean the variables), if you are comfortable with matrix algebra then the estimator of $\beta_4$ is given by (where the variable education=$X_e$ and expereince=$X_c$),
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}_4 &= (X_e'X_e)^{-1}X_e'y \\
&\text{substituting $y$ with the true model:} \\
\hat{\beta}_4 &= (X_e'X_e)^{-1}X'_e(X_e\beta_1 + X_c\beta_2 + v) \\
\hat{\beta}_4 &= (X_e'X_e)^{-1}X'_e X_e\beta_1 + (X_e'X_e)^{-1}X'_e X_c\beta_2 + (X_e'X_e)^{-1}X'_e v \\  
\hat{\beta}_4 &= I\beta_1 + (X_e'X_e)^{-1}X'_e X_c\beta_2 + (X_e'X_e)^{-1}X'_e v \\  
\Rightarrow E[ \beta_1 ] &= \beta_2 + \underbrace{E[(X_e'X_e)^{-1}X'_e X_c]\beta_2}_{bias} + (X_e'X_e)^{-1}\underbrace{E[X'_e v]}_{=0 \text{ by assumption}}
\end{align}

If the variables are scalars $\beta_4$ can be expressed as,
\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{\beta_4} = \frac{\Cov(\expr, wage)}{\Var(\expr)}
\end{eqnarray}

Substitute in the expression for wage (i.e., the long regression) and you will end up with,

\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{\beta_4} = \beta_1 + \beta_2\frac{\Cov(\expr, \educ)}{\Var(\expr)}
\end{eqnarray} 
Assuming that $\Cov(\educ, v)=0$.

Hope this helped.

Comment: This is a nice answer. Welcome to the site. I hope we'll see more. However, given that the question was probably a homework question (as you recognize), please note our [policies](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) about answering HW Qs (even if after several months).